# Alteração de dados Mysql com C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Estou tentando alterar dados salvos no meu BD, porém pelo está tendo um certo erro, se alguém puder dar uma luz

[image: problema]

código que estou usando para salvar as alterações:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
 conectar.Close();
            conectar.Open();
            //Convertendo

            Converter = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantidade.Text);



            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "UPDATE  Produto SET Nome = '" + txtNome.Text + 
                "', Quantidade = '" + txtQuantidade.Text + "', peca =" + cbxPeca.Text + 
                ", Data_entrada = " + DTPEntrada.Text + " WHERE ID_Pacote =" + alterar2 +  " ";

            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            alterar2 = 0;
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtQuantidade.Text = "";
            //txtDescricao.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Pacote alterado", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();


        }
```

e aqui é como eu puxo as informações para os `textboxs` pra editá-las:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        alterar2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        txtNome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cbxPeca.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtQuantidade.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        DTPEntrada.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    }
```

código do banco de Dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE ProdPacote;
USE ProdPacote;

CREATE TABLE Produto(
ID_Produto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Preco DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`status` TINYINT NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Pacote(
ID_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
peca VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Quantidade INT NOT NULL,
Data_entrada DATETIME NOT NULL);





CREATE TABLE Produto_Pacote(
ID_Produto_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Data_Hora DATE NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Produto INT NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Pacote INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT Produto_Pacote
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID_Produto)
REFERENCES Produto (ID_Produto),

CONSTRAINT Pacote_Produto
FOREIGN KEY(FK_ID_Pacote)
REFERENCES Pacote(ID_Pacote));
```

Comment: Neste outro [Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373424/erro-ao-salvar-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-bd-em-c/373432?noredirect=1#comment742325_373432) consegui resolver o erro com a ajuda de alguns membros

Answer (score 0):

Eu também tenho um programa que tenho que alterar os dados da base de dados e utilizo este código (Tens que o colocar no botão de alterar) :

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                DataRow row = ((DataRowView)item.DataBoundItem).Row;
                Database.DatabaseAPI.NonQuery("UPDATE NomeDaTabela SET NomeDaColuna = '" + textBox1.Text + "' WHERE NomeDaColuna  = '" + row["NomeDaColuna "].ToString() + "'");
                MessageBox.Show("Dados Alterados com sucesso!");
                textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

            }
```

O "Database.DatabaseAPI" é o nome que eu dei para fazer as ligações com a base de dados, experimenta e vê se consegues utilizar.

Comment: então é que meu código está dentro de um `if` acabei colocando so a parte do `else` que é quando altera, porém ainda da o erro, eu vou colocar o código do banco

Comment: Verifique também se na base de dados tem o nome da coluna bem escrito, ou mesmo ai no código.

Comment: então eu coloquei, o que é estranho porque fui no banco dei um CTRL+V e CTRL+C para pegar a tabela do banco

Comment: Consegui descobrir o problema no update voce tem "UPDATE Produto" e não é Produto é Pacote altere e veja se conseguiu.

Comment: funcionou, porém no `cbxpeca` da esse erro :
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'teste2' in 'field list''

Comment: tente por assim : 

peca = '" + cbxPeca.Text + "'   (Acho que estava a faltar uma aspa simples, pois como é uma textbox tem que se por aspa simples e dupla aspa)

Comment: mas ai o `Data_entrada` fica com erro

Comment: O que você ta usando para por o data entrada ?
podia estar a utilizar um *datetimepicker* que ficava bem mais fácil, mas isso é na minha opinião.

Comment: Caso você ja tenha um *datetimepicker* tente meter este  codigo antes do inserir: 

string data = "CONVERT(VARCHAR, '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', 103)";

assim antes de você escrever:

Data_entrada = " + DTPEntrada.Text + "   troca o DTPEntrada.Text por data.

Comment: já tenho sim, é ele mesmo que estou usando

Comment: tente escrever o código que eu coloquei em cima para ver se funciona

Comment: não rodou, ele não manda nesse formato, eu queria pegar só a data

Comment: Bom voltei o código com o primeiro erro arrumando, se eu conseguir resolver coloco a solução aqui

Comment: Se você só quiser a data e não as horas basta apenas tirar do formato a parte do (HH:mm:ss), pois é esta parte que define as horas.

Comment: então eu tirei do `DataTimePicke` e a hora não é enviada pro banco, porque ao cadastrar ele não cadastra com horas

Comment: Agora fiquei sem entender o que devia de fazer, ficou meio que confuso.