# Erro ao salvar alteração no BD em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Estou com um certo erro ao fazer alterações de algum Dado cadastrado no banco de dados, imagem a baixo do erro

[image: Imagem do erro]

segue também o código usado:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            conectar.Open();
            //Convertendo

            Converter = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantidade.Text);
            converterdata = Convert.ToDateTime(DTPEntrada.Text);


            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "UPDATE  Pacote SET Nome = '" + txtNome.Text + 
                "', Quantidade = '" + Converter + "', peca =" + cbxPeca.Text + 
                ", Data_entrada = " + converterdata + " WHERE ID_Pacote =" + alterar2 +  " ";


            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            alterar2 = 0;
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtQuantidade.Text = "";
            //txtDescricao.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Pacote alterado", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();


        }
```

Segue também o Código do Banco:

```
    CREATE DATABASE ProdPacote;
USE ProdPacote;

CREATE TABLE Produto(
ID_Produto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Preco DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`status` TINYINT NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Pacote(
ID_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
peca VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Quantidade INT NOT NULL,
Data_entrada DATETIME NOT NULL);





CREATE TABLE Produto_Pacote(
ID_Produto_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Data_Hora DATE NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Produto INT NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Pacote INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT Produto_Pacote
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID_Produto)
REFERENCES Produto (ID_Produto),

CONSTRAINT Pacote_Produto
FOREIGN KEY(FK_ID_Pacote)
REFERENCES Pacote(ID_Pacote));
```

Comment: Tem muito problema no seu código Pietro, o insert está extremamente vulnerável a SQL injection com o código dessa forma, além do erro na concatenação que faz com que nem a inserção funcione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal é fazer o insert como no exemplo abaixo:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE  Pacote SET Nome = ?Nome, Quantidade = ?Quantidade, 
                   peca = Peca ,Data_entrada = ?Data WHERE ID_Pacote = ?ID";

cmd.Parameters.Add("?Nome", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNome.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Quantidade", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Converter;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?peca", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbxPeca.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Data", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = converterdata;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = alterar2;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Tem várias perguntas aqui no SOpt que explicam o por que não deve ser como está na sua pergunta:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361517/35358
2. [Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/35358)
3. [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/35358)

Comment: Postamos quase juntos xD, boa resposta.

Comment: @LINQ empate técnico! xD

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni essa resposta não é minha.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann, Obrigado também man, como foi empate técnico usei as duas kkk mas acabou dando mais certo a sua por conta de ser mysql

Answer (score 3):

Tem uma série de problemas aí, mas o problema principal (o que está causando o erro, no caso) é que seu comando SQL está errado. Provavelmente você escreveu algo errado justamente porque é muito difícil de ler esse código cheio de concatenação e entender algo.

Para facilitar a leitura, encontrar o problema e ainda de quebra evitar SQL Injection, use parâmetros.

```
inserir.CommandText = @"UPDATE Pacote SET Nome = @NOME,
                                          Quantidade = @QUANTIDADE, 
                                          Peca = @PECA, 
                                          Data_entrada = @DT_ENTRADA 
                                          WHERE ID_Pacote = ID_PACOTE"

command.Parameters.Add("@NOME", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@NOME"].Value = txtNome.Text;
// ... Continue para todos os parâmetros
```

Agora que reescrevi seu SQL, percebi os erros:

- O valor de `Quantidade` está entre aspas - imagino que seja um inteiro;
- O valor de `Peca` não está entre aspas

Comment: peca é na verdade um `text`, ou seja é um `ComboBox`, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: deu certo, obrigado man xD, o código só precisava da linha de conexão com o mysql

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni de boa. Você pode marcar a resposta que te ajudou como correta usando o V do lado esquerdo.

Comment: não sabia dessa função obrigado mais uma vez